# What is the estimated variance of Nelson-Aalen?

Tags: statistics, variance

> The Nelson-Aalen estimator is
> $ \hat{\Lambda}(t) = \sum \frac {d_j}{r_j}.$

> I specifically want to use **Greenwood's Formula** such that

> $$ Var(\hat{S}(t)) = \hat{S}(t)^2\sum_j \frac{d_j}{r_j(r_j-d_j)}$$

Now, using the NA estimator, we can use some identities to show

$$ \hat{S}(t) = e^{-\hat{\Lambda}(t)}$$

Then

$$ Var(\hat{S}(t)) = e^{-\hat{\Lambda}(t)} \sum_j \frac{d_j}{r_j(r_j-d_j)} $$

I want to find $Var(\hat{\Lambda}(t))$ from this, but $log(Var(\hat{S}(t))\neq Var(log(\hat{S}(t)).$ So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It has been years since I've touched this material, but I'll give it a shot. This procedure is outlined in p. 233 of *Loss Models: From Data to Decisions*, 4th ed., by Klugman, Panjer, and Willmot.

Assume the number of deaths at time $t_i$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $r_ih(t_i)$, where $h$ is the hazard rate. Its variance is thus $r_ih(t_i)$, with $h(t_i) \approx d_i / r_i$, so the approximate variance is thus $r_i(d_i/r_i) = d_i$.

Assuming independence,
$$\widehat{\text{Var}}(\widehat{\Lambda}(t)) = \widehat{\text{Var}}\left(\sum \dfrac{d_j}{r_j} \right) = \sum\dfrac{\widehat{\text{Var}}(d_j)}{r_j^2} \approx \sum\dfrac{d_j}{r_j^2}\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks, but i'm specifically looking for a method using Greenwood's Formula.. I'm just struggling with the last step

Comment: @CCZ23 Assuming you meet the asymptotic conditions, you could try using the Delta method... I can't say I remember what all of the notation means, though.